# Affinity Designer Toggle Snapping

Tags: snapping, affinity-designer

I'm using Affinity Designer (excellent program).

Maybe I'm silly, but I can't find this anywhere: is there a hotkey for toggling the snapping?  Sometimes it's useful for just one operation, and I don't want to mouse over and click the button.

Thanks!

Comment: This has been updated in the latest release, not only snapping but pixel snapping as well.

Comment: @Brett Excellent, thanks.  Want to share what the hotkey is/will be?  (I've found that AD's documentation on these sorts of things can be lacking; sometimes it's like trying to find easter eggs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't one. Adobe Illustrator has the same "issue", and Affinity  shares many (if not all) shortcuts with Illustrator. The only way is to click the snapping button on the menu.

Comment: Thanks.  I hope they add it at some point, or make the keyboard shortcuts customizable.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your question. I was thinking it was 'does Affinity have snapping'... because the snapping was originally terrible, but it has gotten much better. So, there is No Hotkey currently to turn snapping on/off, because you use the Snapping Manager panel. You could request this, through their forum, and they are pretty good about getting back to you with any questions.